# The sort command in linux does not work "correctly"

Tags: linux, sorting

I'm working on Linux, the `sort` command returns not as expected.

Input text:

```
$ cat input.txt
rep1_1.fq
rep1_2.fq
rep12_1.fq
rep12_2.fq
```

Command and output:

```sh
$ sort input.txt
rep1_1.fq
rep12_1.fq
rep12_2.fq
rep1_2.fq


$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.28
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and Paul Eggert.
```

After sorting, I expected `rep1_2.fq` would be after `rep1_1.fq`, but the result is different.

**Solved**

according to @Federico klez Culloca's advice, use `LC_ALL=C`

```sh
$ LC_ALL=C sort input.txt
rep12_1.fq
rep12_2.fq
rep1_1.fq
rep1_2.fq
```

**Edited**

use `LC_ALL=C` also fix sorting files in a directory.

in case there are four files in current directory:

```sh
$ LC_ALL= ls
rep1_1.fq  rep12_1.fq  rep12_2.fq  rep1_2.fq

$ LC_ALL=C ls
rep12_1.fq  rep12_2.fq  rep1_1.fq  rep1_2.fq
```

Comment: Try this `LC_ALL=C sort input.txt`. See the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html): "*** WARNING *** The locale specified by the environment affects sort order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values."

Comment: Thanks so much, problem fixed.  I find my default LC_ALL was empty, after appending `export LC_ALL=C` to `~/.bashrc` file, `sort` command works.

Comment: I always chuckle a bit when I see a title like "The xyz command doesn't work correctly in Linux" (or in C, etc..) 99.99999% of the time, it isn't the command that is at fault.

Comment: Sure, I totally agree with you, it's not the **command**'s fault, but the way to use it. While, this kind of title could tell what happened to users in direct way.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `version-sort`. From the manual:

```
       -V, --version-sort
          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

This is the output using your example:

```
$ sort -V input.txt 
rep1_1.fq
rep1_2.fq
rep12_1.fq
rep12_2.fq
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It's an alternative way to fix my problem. I see Federico klez Culloca's method using "by native byte values" works better.